# Oracle database TRIGGER does not work in some case

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

The Oracle database has a table with multiple columns, with 1 column named DATEMODIFIED.
When I update the table via script:

```
UPDATE TABLE1
  SET AMOUNT = 10
WHERE ID IN (3,4,5,6,7); 
COMMIT;
```

Then the date is column named DATEMODIFIED would be updated automatically.
I can find the trigger code as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SET_TABLE1_DATEMODIFIED
  BEFORE UPDATE ON TABLE1 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :NEW.DATEMODIFIED := SYSDATE;
END;
```

However, I can find multiple instances that the AMOUNT value was update, without triggering a change in DATEMODIFIED. How can the Oracle system achieve such change? Are there anyway query can amend database values disregarding TRIGGER statements?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, one of the following options

- The trigger didn't exist when the row was updated
- The trigger was disabled when the row was updated
- Some other SQL statement set `lastModified` to `null`

Of course, there is also the possibility that you are not accurately identifying cases where the `amount` was updated.  For example, perhaps someone or something deleted the row and re-inserted it rather than doing an actual `update`.

Comment: Thank you! It means I should look for statements that disable TRIGGER.

Answer (score 0):

Several options I can think about:

- trigger fires before **update**, which means that `INSERT INTO` wouldn't fire it
- trigger was created AFTER those `amount` values were updated (so there were no triggers to be fired)
- trigger was disabled / dropped before those `amount` values were updated, and then enabled / recreated